# CubeIDE does have the manage embedded packages inactive (installing Cube.AI)

Tags: stm32

I am not sure how many people use STMCubeIDE to program STM32 micros. Apparently this is a combination of the STMCubeMX tool with an IDE.

I am trying to add Cube.AI the package of AI to it following tutorials such as [in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=grgNXdkmzzQ). In minute 2.12 you can see that the user adds Cube.AI to MX using the "Manage embedded packages" from the menu (and also from a button)

This button is nowhere in CubeIDE and the menu option is inactive.

Can anybody tell me how to install Cube.AI to CubeIDE??

Answer (score 1):

1st click on "check for updates" to make sure your STM32CubeMX is up to date , 
then restart and install the CUBE-AI package. 
you may need to run the application as an admin.
I am using STM32CubeMX Version 5.5.0  and it's working fine

Answer (score 1):

Help > Manage Embedded Software Packages. That's it.

[image]